# How can I solve this annoying error with const and reference along with STL?

Tags: c++, constructor, stl, constants

The detail code can be found [here in detail](https://ideone.com/RW4iK7).

### Main.cpp

```
#include "Point2d.h"
#include "Line2d.h"
#include "Rectangle2d.h"
#include "MatrixMemory.h"
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point2d> points;
    std::vector<Line2d> lines;
    std::vector<Rectangle2d> rectangles;
    //std::vector<MatrixMemory> matMem;
    //std::vector<Matrix> mat;

    return 0;
}
```

I am having this error message:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Matrix, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'Matrix', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Compiling...
1>reference.fixer.cpp
1>2d.tran.cpp
1>Rectangle2d.cpp
1>Polygon2d.cpp
1>Line2d.cpp
1>Bits.cpp
1>Vector2d.cpp
1>MatrixMemory.cpp
1>.\MatrixMemory.cpp(32) : error C2662: 'MatrixMemory::GetItem' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MatrixMemory' to 'MatrixMemory &'
1>        Conversion loses qualifiers
1>Matrix.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>translation.3d.cpp
1>translation.2d.cpp
1>scaling.2d.cpp
1>rotation.2d.cpp
1>clipping.2d.weiler.atherton.cpp
1>clipping.2d.sutherland.hodgman.cpp
1>clipping.2d.midpoint.subdiv.cpp
1>clipping.2d.liang.barsky.cpp
1>clipping.2d.cohen.sutherland.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Build log was saved at "file://e:\Developer-Workspace\MyGraphicsLibraryImplementation\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Matrix - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The error message is from the following code segment:

```
MatrixMemory.cpp
...................................

MatrixMemory & MatrixMemory :: operator=(const MatrixMemory  & rhs)
{
    if(rowSize!=rhs.rowSize || colSize!=rhs.colSize)
    {
        DeallocateMemory();
        AllocateMemory(rhs.rowSize, rhs.rowSize);
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<rowSize ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<colSize ; j++)
        {
            this->SetItem(i, j, rhs.GetItem(i, j));
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

void MatrixMemory :: SetItem(int r, int c, double value)
{   
    if((r>=0 && r<rowSize) && rowSize>0)
    {
        if((c>=0 && c<colSize) && colSize>0)
        {
            data[r][c] = value;
        }
    }   
}

double MatrixMemory :: GetItem(int r, int c)
{
    double ret = INVALID;

    if((r>=0 && r<rowSize) && rowSize>0)
    {
        if((c>=0 && c<colSize) && colSize>0)
        {
            ret = data[r][c];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

As you can see, It is not possible to declare`MatrixMemory::GetItem` as const.
Coz, it contains some logics.

How to get around the problem?

---

**Down-voters and close-voters, can you please clarify the reason?**

Comment: It contains some logic, but as I can see it does not change any member variables, so you can use the `const` qualifier on this function.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with STL.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `rhs.GetItem(i, j)` in the assignment operator, the compiler requires that `rsh` be non-constant. This is because `GetItem` is not declared a constant member function. However, `rhs` is declared a constant reference, hence the error.

Declare it `const` to fix the problem:

```
double GetItem(int r, int c) const; // line 383; also on line 466
//                           ^^^^^
```

This allows you to call your `GetItem` member function on constant objects, or through `const` pointers and references.

Comment: But, I have no option of declaring `rhs` as a non-constant. Coz, then that will generate an error relating to overloaded assignment and copy const. Isn't so?

Comment: @BROY Although technically you can make `rhs` non-`const`, that would be a bad idea, because it would severely limit the applicability of your copy constructor. The copy constructor that you have now (i.e. with `const` reference) is the proper way of making copy constructors in C++.